# Django show notification to User between the two dates

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make a notification application on my web application. I want users to see notifications from the Admin panel that set the start and end dates to be displayed during those hours.

```
class NotificationModel(model.Model):
    start = models.DatetimeField()
    end   = models.DatetimeField()
```

I have to do this without using Redis.I'll add notifications from the Admin panel that I want to show users.
When I add, these notifications should only be displayed on the site between start and end dates
How can I do that?
Should I do it using the filter method through my model?

Comment: you can do something like this `NotificationModel.objects.filter(date__range=[start,end])`

Comment: date__range  (date) There is no field in the my model. There are start and end fields.

Comment: If there is a notification that is active as soon as the user enters the site, I want it to appear

Comment: i think you are not showing your model fields ,could you show the whole field ? i mean you have to have a foreignkey to know which notification belongs to which user and in general it is better to have just an end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Q() objects. For more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects

```
NotificationModel.objects.filter(
    Q(start__lte=datetime.now()) &
    Q(end__gte=datetime.now())
)
```